# Mojo::UserAgent clear session data

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I have some code which using Mojo::UserAgent

after the second request i see some cookies on the header which come from the first request , how is it possible to remove those cookies from the second request using the same agent

without writing for every request

```
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new
```

Comment: If you want to simulate multiple users, you should create a new user agent for every user instead of emptying the cookie jar. It's clearer.

Answer (score 4):

That should do it:

```
$ua->cookie_jar()->empty();
```

The whole purpose of cookies is to have a state between each request. If you need to empty them, I think you may have a completely different problem.